Mathematica LinearSolve with additional constraints
I want to solve a linear Matrix equation over GF(2). I am currently using Mathematica's LinearSolve[A,B, Modulus->2] function to solve for X in the equation AX = B.
Since A and B each have some redundant columns, there are multiple solutions to X.

Firstly, Is there a way to add conditions on X in the LinearSolve
function? For example, X may be constrained to be unitary (within
this binary GF(2) set-up constraint), or that rows in X need to have
a certain parity. Or that X needs to be a submatrix of a bigger
matrix.
Currently the constraint I am interested in is that none of the
columns of X are all 0 i.e. all columns have hamming weight
at least one.

Alternatively, if there is a way to print out all solutions for an undetermined matrix, that would help too.
Currently I see the Mathematica has the following option which would find all solutions to a system of equations:
{x, y, z} /. 
 Solve[{{1, 2, 3}, {4, 5, 6}} . {x, y, z} == {6, 15}, {x, y}]

I want to be able to implement this for an unknown matrix X which could be large so I don't have to manually set variables like {x,y,z} for all entries individually. Additionally I'll still be solving in mod 2.

There is no simple option of LinearSolve to fulfill your requrements.
If I were you, I will adopt the following strategy:
(1) Store all the solutions (mod 2) of the linear equation produced by LinearSolve into some variable as a List.
(2) Pick admissible solutions from the list using Select[], Cases[] or DeleteCases[].

Thanks! This is a good strategy. Currently LinearSolve only prints out one solution for me- is there a way to access all possible solutions?

is there a way to access all possible solutions? — Have you seen NullSpace[]?

Here RHS, B, is non-zero, and not a vector but a matrix (so a bunch of individual vectors, at least a few of which are non-zero). So NullSpace[] wouldn't straightforwardly work.

Oh, I thought you could figure it out. I'll post my idea as an answer.

Response to a comment below the OP:
Below LinearSolve[] returns a particular solution xmat0. The general solution is constructed from the nullspace of the A matrix amat. The solution space has dimension $kn$ for an $n\times n$ matrix with a kernel of dimension $k$.
SeedRandom[5];
amat = RandomInteger[1, {10, 10}];
bmat = amat . RandomInteger[1, {10, 10}];
xmat0 = LinearSolve[amat, bmat, Modulus -> 2];
nullmatrices = 
  Join[{#}, ConstantArray[0, Dimensions@xmat0 - {1, 0}]] & /@ 
   NullSpace[amat, Modulus -> 2];
xmat = xmat0 + Sum[
    a[i, j] Transpose@RotateRight[nullmatrices[[i]], j]
    , {i, Length@nullmatrices}, {j, Length@xmat0[[1]]}];
amat . xmat - bmat // PolynomialMod[#, 2] &
(*
{{0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0},
 {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0},
 {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0},
 {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0},
 {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0},
 {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0},
 {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0},
 {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0},
 {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0},
 {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}}
*)

The matrix amat has a kernel of dimension 2:
Length@nullmatrices
(*  2  *)

Then one can put constraints on the parameters C[i, j] as desired.

Thanks! I'm new to mathematica, so pl bear with a follow-up question - How does one fix the parameters of the solution one obtains this way?
Here the nullspace has dimension 2, so I assume fixing 2 independent free variables will give me a specific instance of a solution (generating one of 2^2=4 possible different vectors )

@clearski Yes the nullspace of $A$ has dimension $2$. But the linear problem you're solving is from matrices to matrices, not vectors to vectors; that is, ${\Bbb R}^{n \times n} \rightarrow {\Bbb R}^{n \times n}$, not ${\Bbb R}^{n} \rightarrow {\Bbb R}^{n}$. So $v \mapsto Av$ in vectors induces a mapping $X \mapsto AX$, basically a product of $n$ copies (one for each column of $X$) of the first mapping. The kernel of the second mapping has dimension $k n$, where $k$ is the dimension of the nullspace of $A$. In the example, the dimension is $2 \times 10 = 20$....

...The parameters are a[i, j], where i runs from 1 to 2 ($1\le i \le k$) and j runs from 1 to 10 ($1 \le j \le n$). Solving for the Hamming weight, assuming it is the count of the number of nonzero entries and not the sum (mod 2) of the entries seems tricky. If you set up your algebra mod 2, then the Hamming weight is not a sum, and I'm not sure built-in solvers are set up for that. Maybe using $(X_{11} = 1\ \Vert\ X_{21} = 1\ \Vert\ \cdots)\ &&\ (X_{12} = 1 \ \Vert\ X_{22} = 1\ \Vert\ \cdots)\ &&\ \cdots$ would work....

Something like Reduce[And @@ Or @@@ Map[# == 1 &, xmat, {2}], Modulus -> 2] (runs forever). Try it on test = xmat[[2 ;; 4, 2 ;; 4]]; Reduce[And @@ Or @@@ Thread /@ Thread[test == 1], Modulus -> 2] first. (You can print test and xmat to see what they are; xmat is intimidating. :)

Yeah, xmat is indecipherable when you print it as is. Thanks a ton for the code to test and run this on a smaller system. I'll also try to look a way to print progress on that longer calculation that runs forever.

PseudoInversegives the minimal solution
PseudoInverse[{{1, 2, 3}, {4, 5, 6}}] . {6, 15}
(* {1,1,1} *)


Does this work mod 2 (that is, over GF(2))?
